# Angular 5 populate selected option from database in edit form

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ngmodel, ngfor, ngmodel

I was able to list and add the select options as shown below:

```html
   <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="feed.feed_store" name="feed_store" placeholder="Select Store">
      <option *ngFor="let feedstore of feedstores" [value]="feedstore">{{ feedstore }}</option>
    </select>
```

Now in my edit form I want to show the selected option from the database.
Not sure to about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `selected` attribute to the option based on a condition like so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="feed">
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="feed.feed_store" name="feed_store" placeholder="Select Store">
          <option *ngFor="let feedstore of feedstores" 
                 [value]="feedstore"
                 [selected]="feedstore === 'feedstore_from_database'">
              {{ feedstore }}
          </option>
    </select>
<ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `selected` attribute to the option based on a condition like so:

    
          
              {{ feedstore }}

Comment: Getting this error:

`EditFeedComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'feed_store' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EditFeedComponent.html:9)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14640)`

Comment: this has nothing to do with the changes I made to your code. it means that the `feed` object you are binding your ngModel to is undefined.

Comment: try wrapping your code in an ng-container:
<ng-container *ngIf="feed">your code goes here...</ng-container>